# Python TypeError: expected string or buffer using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run a Python script to extract certain column from an Excel file.

I found Pandas might be a good solution, so I tried with following code:

```
import pandas

for filename in InFileslist:
    fields = ['MRN']
    df = pandas.read_excel(filename, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
    print df.keys()
    print df.MRN
```

And below is the error message that I got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/FetchingData_v3.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/api.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.io.gbq import read_gbq
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 52, in <module>
    if LooseVersion(_GOOGLE_FLAGS_VERSION >= '2.0.0'):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 265, in __init__
self.parse(vstring)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/version.py", line 274, in parse
self.component_re.split(vstring))
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I am not sure whether this is something to do with Pandas installation issue or code issue.

Comment: Is it excel? You will want `pandas.read_excel` instead.

Comment: I modified the code as shown (from: pandas.read_csv --> pandas.read_excel), but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you clarify if it's a csv or an xlsx?

Comment: Looks like it is nothing to do with code. I commented out the codes, and getting the same error. When I commented out "import pandas", error is gone. It is xls file.

Comment: I see. Are you on the latest pandas version? If not, better upgrade to 0.20.

Comment: I tried with this command. 1) sudo apt-get install python-pip  2) sudo pip install numpy  3) sudo pip install pandas  Would it be sufficient?

Comment: Also do `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, no problem.